# Give proper permissions for Elasticsearch to access Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch, access-denied

I installed elasticsearch on an Ubuntu VM, and added java afterwards, since it was missing. But when I launch the elasticsearch it runs for a few seconds and crashes. In logs I found the following message:

```
[2021-10-26T09:36:37,275][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node1] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.jdk.internal.vm.annotation")
  at _unknown_
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.jdk.internal.vm.annotation")
```

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch have you installed? Version 7.X already comes with a bundled Java distribution and there is no need to install Java system wide. Also, which version of Java you installed? Not all versions are compatible.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thank you, completely forgot about that. I was playing around with elasticsearch Chef cookbook and it installed version 5.X. Your comment solves my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @leandrojmp said the version 7.x comes with java so just install that. Kudos to him, that solves my problem!